# Why do menu item background image looks different on different phones?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-menu

I have a menu item in actionbar of my app. I am setting a background image for that menu item using following line of code:

```
 menu.findItem(R.id.refresh_item).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_bg);
```

It works fine with my samsung s3. But when i run this app on Nexus phone then it looks very small.

Following are the screen shots for both phones.

For Samsung s3:

[image]

and for Nexus:

[image]

Any idea why is it looking different in Nexus phone and how can i fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you created the icon for all pixel densities ?

Comment: You should use different images for different pixel densities, which varies according to devices. Use different images for HDPI, LDPI and MDPI.

Comment: Now i made 3 different images with pixels: 120*90, 160*120, 240*180 and put them in drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi. Resolution is same for all images. But it did not make any difference

Comment: @Piscean Did you find a solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Akash No bro. I changed my design instead. Still looking for answer :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep seperate images for different screen resolution. You current image is apt for S3 whihc has xhdpi resolution but looks bad o nexus which has different screen density (latest nexus is xxhppi). Create another drawable (drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi) and keep proper resolution images in them.

Follow the link below for details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: Right now i am using an image with size 122*90 and resolution 96. Can you tell me that for xxhdpi which size and resolution should i use for same background image?

Comment: its based on the ratio. I would suggest you to check the links I mentioned above. You will get all answers. Its very important concept. Give some time to read the links.

Comment: i read that document and as i understood if mhdpi background size is 80*60 then xxhdpi size should be 240*180. I tried that but it did not work. Did i understand it wrong?

Comment: yes the ratio is mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi -> 1x:1.5x:2x:3x. Which nexus are you using? Is it xxhdpi or some older version of nexus? Is 80*60 image working fine for mdpi screen?

Comment: I have only samsung s3 and galaxy nexus. I made png images and put it in every folder. 80*60 for mdpi, 120*90 for hdpi, 160*120 for xhdpi and 240*180 for xxhdpi. All images have same name (icon_bg.png). I think now it should be automatically picked by android. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: which version of galaxy nexus? it is nexus tab?

Comment: Its an menu item. Do i need to set size for menu item as well. Right now i am just setting background image.